# Adding output data to 1 text file

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet, get-childitem

As you can see below, the content from all .msg files within a folder is extracted. However, I can only see 1 .msg content in the output content.txt and not all the .msg files. How can I loop the command and add to the same .txt file?

```cs
$output_file3 = ‘c:\outlook_files\content.txt’

# Search messages
Get-ChildItem "c:\outlook_files\msg\" -Filter *.msg | Foreach-Object {
    # Read current message content
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName >$output_file3
}
```

Comment: `Get-Help 'about_Redirection' -ShowWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using redirection, use `Out-File -append` or `Add-Content`

so change

`$content = Get-Content $_.FullName >$output_file3`

to

`Get-Content $_.FullName | out-file $output_file3 -append`

I dropped the variable assignment because it is not doing anything in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` [redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) truncates existing files. Either use an append operation:

```
Get-Content $_.FullName >>$output_file3
Get-Content $_.FullName | Add-Content $output_file3
Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File $output_file3 -Append
```

or do the write operation after the `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName
} >$output_file3

ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName
} | Set-Content $output_file3

ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName
} | Out-File $output_file3
```

Normally you'd prefer the `*-Content` or `Out-File` cmdlets over redirection operators, because they give you better control over what's written to the file (namely the encoding). The main difference between `Out-File` and `Set-Content`/`Add-Content` is that the former defaults to Unicode (little endian UTF-16 to be precise), whereas the latter default to Ascii (actually the [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) ANSI encoding).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply if you dont want loop for nothing

```
Get-Content "c:\outlook_files\msg\\*.msg" | Out-File "c:\outlook_files\content.txt"
```

or

```
Get-Content "c:\outlook_files\msg\\*.msg" > "c:\outlook_files\content.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use add content like this example :

```
add-content -path "c:\test.txt" -value "$value"
```